# Render Icons using Font-Awesome-Kit into Streamlit Application

Tags: python, font-awesome, streamlit

I'm attempting to add icons using font-awesome-kit into a streamlit application and have tried several different approaches with no success.

**Attempt 1**

Tried importing a JS tag for the component

```
st.write('<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xyz.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
st.write('<i class="fa-duotone fa-calendar-days"></i>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

**Attempt 2**
Tried importing a CSS tag for the component

```
st.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/zax.css" crossorigin="anonymous">', unsafe_allow_html=True)
st.write('<i class="fa-duotone fa-calendar-days"></i>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

**Attempt 3**
Tried using streamlit HTML component to render the icon component.

```
st.components.v1.html('<i class="fa-duotone fa-calendar-days"></i>')
```

As a workaround, I'm currently using a cloudflare's CDN as described in the code below which successfully render's the icon.

```
import streamlit as st
st.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"/>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
st.write('<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"/>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

However, when using the tool-kit not receiving any output where the icon is expected.  Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this example](https://autobencoder.com/2022-03-10-streamlit-fontawesome/) by Ben Heil?

```
def load_text(file_path):
"""A convenience function for reading in the files used for the site's text"""
with open(file_path) as in_file:
    return in_file.read()
                                                                            
                                                                            
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    # Other demo code omitted for clarity

st.write('### Component Example')
# HTML component
component_example = load_text('awesome.html')
st.components.v1.html(component_example)
```